# Spring Boot, receive two incoming client requests and send a combined response back to both clients

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I want to create an endpoint that takes a string as request. And when it receives two requests, it combines the request strings from both the clients and sends it back as the common response to both.

I tried to create the endpoint using Spring Weblux by returning an SSE stream to the client with Mono and Sink. When first client request is received, it saves the received string as a class variable and returns a Mono. When the second request is received, it confirms that the class variable is filled with the previous request string, combines with that and emits it as the response to both.

**Controller Class:**

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController.class);

    Sinks.One<String> combined;
    
    // i think multiple threads try to access this, causing problems
    String lastReqString = null;
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/combine/{incomingString}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Mono<String> combine(@PathVariable String incomingString) {
        log.info("START incomingString: {} last: {}", incomingString, lastReqString);
        
        if(lastReqString==null) {
            // if request is is first
            log.info("lastReqString: NULL, incomingString: {} lastReqString: {}", incomingString, lastReqString);
            combined = Sinks.one(); // refreshing sink for next request, is there a better way to do so?
            lastReqString = incomingString;
            
        } else {
            // if request is is second
            log.info("lastReqString: INFLATED, incomingString: {} lastReqString: {}", incomingString, lastReqString);
            combined.tryEmitValue(lastReqString + " " + incomingString);
            lastReqString = null; // refreshing for upcoming request pairs
        }
        
        return combined.asMono();
    }
}
```

My problem is, when I receive multiple requests, some requests do not combine and complete. I think it is because when multiple requests are received at the same time, different threads are trying to access the lastReqString variable together and getting null. As you can see in the logs below, out of 4 requests received, the last 2 request's logs (last 4 logs) are of same time "16:19:40.604" and both are showing the lastReqString as null. Even though first request should replace it by it's own string for the next to see and combine.

```
2023-05-09 16:19:40.094  INFO 22332 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] com.learning.controller.TestController   : START incomingString: c893c185-9334-4b8d-abae-a7ccdb0d38d5 last: null
2023-05-09 16:19:40.094  INFO 22332 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] com.learning.controller.TestController   : lastReqString: NULL, incomingString: c893c185-9334-4b8d-abae-a7ccdb0d38d5 lastReqString: null
2023-05-09 16:19:40.598  INFO 22332 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] com.learning.controller.TestController   : START incomingString: 6d8aae2d-5bd8-47f5-9b6c-877d53bd82c8 last: c893c185-9334-4b8d-abae-a7ccdb0d38d5
2023-05-09 16:19:40.598  INFO 22332 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] com.learning.controller.TestController   : lastReqString: INFLATED, incomingString: 6d8aae2d-5bd8-47f5-9b6c-877d53bd82c8 lastReqString: c893c185-9334-4b8d-abae-a7ccdb0d38d5
2023-05-09 16:19:40.604  INFO 22332 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] com.learning.controller.TestController   : START incomingString: daa8a056-c9b9-446a-92f6-4dd6d6de3efd last: null
2023-05-09 16:19:40.604  INFO 22332 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] com.learning.controller.TestController   : START incomingString: 0c450f7b-40cc-4c6b-ac7f-8e2050c7f0dd last: null
2023-05-09 16:19:40.604  INFO 22332 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] com.learning.controller.TestController   : lastReqString: NULL, incomingString: daa8a056-c9b9-446a-92f6-4dd6d6de3efd lastReqString: null
2023-05-09 16:19:40.604  INFO 22332 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] com.learning.controller.TestController   : lastReqString: NULL, incomingString: 0c450f7b-40cc-4c6b-ac7f-8e2050c7f0dd lastReqString: null
```

Maybe synchronizing will work but I have heard that we should not use it with Webflux and it may slow down the service. Is it true? If yes, what is the proper way to achieve it in Webflux or if there is some totally different better way to do this entire thing?

Comment: I understand the task, but I don't see its business logic essence. In addition, it can also cause cross-vulnerability because one user can influence/affect another user. What your plan if you will have 100 users? Based on what decisions do you combine the request? If first user waits for 100th user, does response time of first user not will be considerable?

Comment: @Numichi Hi, one example can be, suppose we are making a server for online tic tac toe multiplayer game. It has a feature to connect with any random partner for a match. So they both will start this feature and hit this end point that will create a common match and return it to them. I will not combine all 100 users, will just return one response for 2 users to those 2 users, and next response to upcoming future 2 users.

Comment: I would use a message system or websocket for this. The REST endpoint doesn't optimal for your task.